# VBA Excel ComboBox Error 381

Tags: vba, excel

I've got two subs:

1)

```
Sub InitializeComboBoxes()

Dim lastRowOfPositions As Integer, lastRowOfShifts As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' POPULATE POSITIONS COMBOBOX
lastRowOfPositions = Module2.last_row("Menu", "_positions")
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").PositionsComboBox.List = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").Range(Cells(2, Range("_positions").Column), Cells(lastRowOfPositions, Range("_positions").Column)).Value
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").PositionsComboBox.ListIndex = 0

End Sub
```

2)

```
Sub InitializeEmployeeComboBox()

Dim lastRowOfEmployees As Integer
Dim sheetName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

sheetName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").ShiftsComboBoxRemove.Value
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim helperText As String

helperText = sheetName & "Name"
lastRowOfEmployees = Module2.last_row(sheetName, sheetName & "Name")

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").EmployeesComboBox.List = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, ws.Range(helperText).Column), ws.Cells(lastRowOfEmployees, ws.Range(helperText).Column)).Value
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").EmployeesComboBox.ListIndex = 0

End Sub
```

The problem is with:
1) `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").PositionsComboBox.List = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").Range(Cells(2, Range("_positions").Column), Cells(lastRowOfPositions, Range("_positions").Column)).Value` - this is form first sub and it works fine, no problems

2) `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").EmployeesComboBox.List = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, ws.Range(helperText).Column), ws.Cells(lastRowOfEmployees, ws.Range(helperText).Column)).Value` - from second sub.

For me, they are same piece of code, just here I use Range from different sheet, unlike in (1) where I use Range from same sheet

First one works fine, second gives Error 381
Help please, as I can not find the error causing it

Comment: Have you checked what `ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, ws.Range(helperText).Column), ws.Cells(lastRowOfEmployees, ws.Range(helperText).Column)).Value` gives back as value?

Comment: I can't quite put my finger on it, but I vaguely recall a similar problem I once had which had its reason in where the code was located. Try running your code from a standard code module.

Answer (score 0):

It seem there is a problem when I try to populate ComboBox with range from other sheet. I worked around it by creating an array, populating it with range values and then assigning array to ComboBox